# How to make one clear object invisible inside of another clear object?

Tags: transparency

So for my animation, I have water draining out of a clear sphere. Unfortunately, through the sphere, the flow of water is visible when I don't want it to be. I only want the flow to be visible when it exits the bottom of the sphere.

[image]

I still want the sphere to be translucent to the point where the viewer can see over to the other side, I just don't want to hide the part of the inflow inside the clear sphere.

Does anyone know a way of using a translucent object to hide a section of another object while keeping the former object see-through???

I'm trying to avoid masking it out in post.

A link to my project can be found down below.

[image]

Comment: please use imgur for pictures (there are tools in the question editor to do this.  MS is very slow to load and I don't want to be redirected there just to look at a picture.  Also you can upload blende files to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Hello :). Please make it easier for others to help you, and upload your Blendfile without unnecessary images and geometry. That way you can easily cut down the size from 400+ to 3 MB.

Comment: Sorry it wouldn’t let me upload images larger that 2 MB.

Comment: Hey I just updated my post. I attached the file to blend-exchange and I attached the picture directly to my post.

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick that worked very well for me:

You can make the object "invisible" inside of the clear sphere by adding another sphere just slightly smaller inside of it, adding a Boolean modifier to both the water inside the sphere, and itself. Then set the Boolean sphere to fully transparent so you do not see it. Now the water inside of the sphere should have disappeared. Make sure you do not apply the modifier at all, as that would apply it to the vertices, and change the simulation.

Comment: Now that's a smart way to do it.

Comment: Do I set the boolean sphere to difference or intersect?

Comment: You set it to difference

Comment: You can also play around with the settings to get an appealing result

Answer (score 2):

You can use ***Light Path > Is Singular Ray*** to "mask" inside object out of main object.

Node setup below should be assigned **only** (!) to the object you want to hide. Sphere has simple Glass shader.

Another crucial thing here is **Glass Roughness**. You must add "something" (more then 0.017-0.18) not to break refraction. I've added 0.033.

[image: final]