# how do i make an object only appear through a transparent object?

Tags: materials, shaders, transparency

i have a story, in which a ghost can only be seen through water, i was thinking about making a scene, where theres a water bottle, and you can only see the thing on the other side of the bottle, which is transparent

i've tried playing around with the light path
[image]

and it sorta work, but i wanted it to be reverse, you can see the object through transparency but not the other way around
[image]

so, i decided to change the location of the shader, top to bottom, and bottom to top
[image]

and it sorta work, but the part thats supposed to be transparent becomes black,
[image]

i've tried adding colour ramp and reverse the colour too(black to white, white to black), unfortunately same result. can anybody point me the issue here? kinda stuck.

edit
in respond to Christopher Bennett[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159828/how-to-make-one-clear-object-invisible-inside-of-another-clear-object/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157621/how-can-i-make-an-object-only-visible-through-certain-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164773/is-there-a-way-to-have-an-object-show-up-only-in-a-reflection

Comment: if i understand correctly from the post, i've follow the third one, hence my issue, the other 2 seems to be the same solution. which is why i ended up with my situation right now

Answer (score 1):

Use *Transmission Depth* instead of *Transparent* (only works in cycles):

[image: Transmission]

Fyi - I made a pseudo "water material" for the plane - that explains the offset and the "waviness".

Comment: i did the same setup as you did, but why is it not working for me? am i missing smthing?(the plane on my file is fully transparent btw). please see the new added picture above

Comment: It doesn't workd for _fully_ transparent items (alpha=0). For your water material, instead of going fully transparent, use  a Principled BSDF with the transmission set to 1. You can leave alpha at 1 and it will still be invisible.

Comment: omg!, that work! so i dont need to use transparent shader at all?

Comment: The principled BSDF can make a purely transparent (and I mean _invisible_) plane by changing the Roughness to 0, the Transmission to 1 and the IOR to 1. Also, the default "white" in the basecolor box is a few shades darker than pure white - make sure to put the "whiteness" up all the way to make the plane truly invisible.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but thanks man, that really helps